# Help with installing/configuring Samba 2.2.3a on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, samba, vulnerability

I am having trouble installing and configuring an old version of on Ubuntu 14.04.

I am configuring this specific versionson purpose to be vulnerable for penetration testing.

However, after following all the instructions in each installation file, Samba is not allowing users to connect. I suspect it is 100% my error, and after literally days of searching and trying to fix these issues, I am out of luck.

**Q1:** Does anyone have the experience necessary to look at my Samba configuration file and tell me what might be the issue? See edit for details of the error + config file.

**Q2:** Is there an easier way to install older versions of software? I know this is extremely vague. Any resources that you can point me towards would be much appreciated.

**Q3:** Do you know of any other older, deprecated software that:

1. Is exploitable via Metasploit, and
2. Is able to be found on the Internet for download?

I am no expert at configuring software on Linux at all, much less a deprecated version with less support available. I hope I can get some assistance on this. Thanks a bunch!

=======

Edited to add info about Samba issues: When I try to connect to Samba either from Kali or from within Ubuntu, it gives me this error:

```
session setup failed: NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
```

Also [**here is the `smb.conf` file.**](http://pastebin.com/FwLPxehY)

=======

Edited to reign in the scope of the question to be more specific.

=======

Edited to show my [**potential new smb.conf file**](http://pastebin.com/m9nE95Jd). I got frustrated and completely started over on a fresh Ubuntu 14.04, and currently I'm running into issues with smbd and nmbd not starting.

Comment: There's a `proftpd` tag on this question; is there a proftpd-related issue, or is that tag now not needed?

Comment: My bad. I removed references to ProFTPD since I wanted to focus on the Samba issue.